# how to alias the current folder

Tags: command-line, bash

How can I alias the output of this command?

```
[basename "$PWD"]
```

I basically want to be able to to do

```
git browse [basename "$PWD"]
```

Comment: You don't really need `basename` in Bash: `git browse "${PWD##*/}"`.

Comment: `[basename "$PWD"]` is not valid `bash` syntax, which means you can't alias it... Or rather, you can, as in `alias foo="[basename \"$PWD\"]"`. But the result is rather useless. Perhaps you just want to `git browse .`

Comment: @twalberg yeah i was writing it like that to demonstrate what i was hoping to achieve. Mind offering an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can run this directly: `git browse "$(basename $PWD)"`

Or, you could alias it:

```
alias browsepwd='git browse "$(basename "$PWD")"'
```

Or, you could write a bash function

```
function bnpwd() {
  basename $PWD
}
```

Then you can run `git browse "$(bnpwd)"`.

Or any combination of the above ;)

Comment: Your alias definition is wrong: you mustn't put spaces around the `=` sign, and your double quotes are wrong, you need single quotes: otherwise, the alias will have the value of `$(basename "$PWD")` when it is defined, not when it's used. You need: `alias browsepwd='git browse "$(basename "$PWD")"'` (with all these quotes and no spaces around the `=` sign). Moreover, since `$PWD` may contain spaces, you must quote its expansion everywhere you're using it.

Comment: thanks, I've updated the examples to include quotes!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `git browse`, but I suspect what you want is this:

```
git browse .
```

Your original concept seems a little flawed to me for this reason - suppose my `git` repository is in `/usr/local/projects/widgets`. If I `cd /usr/local/projects/widgets`, then `$PWD` will be `/usr/local/projects/widgets`, and `basename $PWD` will report `widgets`. Unless my project has a subdirectory `widgets`, `git browse $(basename $PWD)` probably isn't right, and even if such a subdirectory does exist, I would guess the result wouldn't be exactly what is expected. On the other hand, depending on exactly `git browse` does with its arguments, `git browse .` is probably essentially equivalent to `git browse $PWD`. They at least reference the same directory.